# Array operations on heterogeneous numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need an efficient heterogeneous array in which the first element is an int and the rest are floats. After creating it, however, basic array operations are exploding.

```
A = np.zeros(1, dtype='i4, f4, f4')
B = np.array([3,3,3])
A + B
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Comment: Why don't you also provide the dtype for B?

Comment: The dtype syntax is creating one - three tuple rather than one - three element array. Look at custom dtypes for np.zeros.

Comment: @bejota that's not what I meant. I meant instead of letting it choose the default int type to use, specify it, or specify record types. If you try to give the dtype `'i4, f4, f4'` for B, the error you get explains why the OP's original request doesn't make sense (you need bytes to interpret an array like that). So use a record type and iterate over the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a structured array like this, operations that call for iteration over the fields generally don't work.

Even adding `A` to itself does not work:

```
In [476]: A = np.zeros(1, dtype='i4, f4, f4')

In [477]: A+A
...
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')]) ....
```

In other words, there's a way of adding an `int` to an `int`, a `float` to an `int`, but not a way of adding a `A` element to another element.

An element of `A` is a `tuple` or a `numpy.void` (depending on how you access it)

```
In [478]: A.item()
Out[478]: (0, 0.0, 0.0)

In [479]: type(A.item())
Out[479]: tuple

In [480]: type(A[0])
Out[480]: numpy.void
```

To work across the fields of a structured array you usually have to iterate over the field names.

```
In [493]: B=np.arange(3)

In [494]: for i,name in enumerate(A.dtype.names):
   A[name] = A[name]+B[i]
   .....: 

In [495]: A
Out[495]: 
array([(0, 1.0, 2.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

If all the fields have the same type, e.g. `dtype='i4, i4, i4'`, then it is possible to view the structured array as a homogeneous dtype, and perform regular math on it.  But with your mix of floats and ints, that isn't possible.