# Numpy, cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am testing a naive Bayes Classifier with Sci-Kit learn and using Numpy for storing the data in arrays. My data is coming from a .csv file and contains a header row, four columns that contain strings and one column that contains numeric values. Here is what the structure of the csv file looks like:

```
columnOne    columnTwo    columnThree    columnFour    columnFive
string       string       string         numeric       string
```

and here is my code:

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import numpy as np
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'rU') as csvfile: 
    location_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',', 
    quotechar ='"') 
    # Header contains feature names 
    row = location_reader.next() 
    feature_names = np.array(row) 
    # Load dataset, and target classes 
    location_X, location_y = [], [] 
    for row in location_reader: 
        location_X.append(row) 
        location_y.append(row[4]) # The target value is column five 
    location_X = np.array(location_X)
    location_y = np.array(location_y)
model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(location_X, location_y)
print(model)
# make predictions
expected = location_y
predicted = model.predict(location_X)
# summarize the fit of the model
print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
```

Can anyone provide some input on why I might be getting this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: It might help if you showed us the `dtype` (and shape) of `location_X`.  But if it is structured array with a compound dtype, there are relatively few operations that `numpy` can perform across rows.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008304/array-operations-on-heterogeneous-numpy-arrays

Comment: Not that it makes a difference here, but people often load `csv` files like this with `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt`.  With `dtype=None` they automatically assign the compound dtype.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here. It looks like you're trying to use strings as features, which doesn't make sense in the context of a Gaussian model (you can't compute the mean or the variance of a list of strings). Also your training vectors actually *contain* the target values, so predicting `location_y` from `location_x` is trivial anyway.